# how to compare two arrays of different length if you dont know the length of each one in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I am stuck in this. I got 2 arrays, I don't know the length of each one, they can be the same length or no, I don't know,  but I need to create a new array with the numbers no common in  just a (2, 10).

For this case:

```
    var a = [2,4,10];
    var b = [1,4];

    var newArray = [];

    if(a.length >= b.length ){
        for(var i =0; i < a.length; i++){
            for(var j =0; j < b.length; j++){
                if(a[i] !=b [j]){
                    newArray.push(b);        
                }        
            }
        }
    }else{}
```

I don't know why my code never reach the first condition and I don't know what to do when b has more length than a.

Comment: Do you want different behaviour when a is shorter than b? Or is this an attempt at making it work?

Comment: Its an attempt to make it work

Comment: Also, are two numbers that are the same but not in the same position considered the same?

Comment: yes they are the same I mean just the 2 and 10

Comment: In that case, my answer below should solve your problem. Verify that the clarification at the bottom is the outcome your are looking for.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It seems that you have a logic error in your code, if I am understanding your requirements correctly.

This code will put all elements that are in `a` that are not in `b`, into `newArray`.

```
var a = [2, 4, 10];
var b = [1, 4];

var newArray = [];

for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    // we want to know if a[i] is found in b
    var match = false; // we haven't found it yet
    for (var j = 0; j < b.length; j++) {
        if (a[i] == b[j]) {
            // we have found a[i] in b, so we can stop searching
            match = true;
            break;
        }
        // if we never find a[i] in b, the for loop will simply end,
        // and match will remain false
    }
    // add a[i] to newArray only if we didn't find a match.
    if (!match) {
        newArray.push(a[i]);
    }
}
```

---

To clarify, if

```
a = [2, 4, 10];
b = [4, 3, 11, 12];
```

then `newArray` will be `[2,10]`

Comment: I alert the newArray and I get 1,4,1,4 I still trying thanks for answering I dont know why your code does not work, have you checked your code?

Comment: @Qeorge, I have found the error. Change the 3rd last line to `newArray.push(a[i]);` as I have in my edit.

Comment: @George, I would encourage you to try and understand why the code works, and why the check for which array is longer is not needed. Think about the problem you where trying to solve and what steps the code should take to get the solution.

Comment: thanks @BudgieInWA any more advise?? I am trying to figure out your code, where did you learn that stuff??

Comment: Practice, practice, practice. I always try to understand *how* code works. If it's too great of a leap for your brain to make at once, look up tutorials on for loops and nested for loops. There's a tutorial on everything, at every difficulty level for everything (almost) out there.

Comment: ok I will try more harder the next time before asking a question here :)

Comment: `a.push(e)` will append `e` to the array `a`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
var a = [2,4,10]; 
var b = [1,4]; 
var nonCommonArray = []; 
for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++){
    if(!eleContainsInArray(b,a[i])){
        nonCommonArray.push(a[i]);
    }
}

function eleContainsInArray(arr,element){
    if(arr != null && arr.length >0){
        for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
            if(arr[i] == element)
                return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: thanks for answering I already accept the previous answer but let me check

Comment: @bentham how did you find this?

Answer (score 2):

I found this solution just using the `filter()` and `include()` methods, a very and short easy one.

The `filter()` method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided function.

The `includes()` method determines whether an array includes a certain value among its entries, returning true or false as appropriate.

```
function compareArrays(a, b) {
  return a.filter(e => b.includes(e));
}
```